# Is it possible to compute the sign of a permutation in linear time?

Tags: numpy, permutation, circular-permutations

I was just wondering if there's a way to compute the sign of a permutation within linear (or at least better than n^2?) time

For example, let's say I have an array of n numbers and I permute two elements within this array which would flip the sign of the permutation. I have a function that can compute this in n^2  time, however, it seems there might be a more efficient algorithm.

I've attached a minimal reproducible example of computing in quadratic time,

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.arange(1,6,1)
pvals = np.arange(1,6,1)
pvals[0], pvals[1] = pvals[1], pvals[0] #swap

def quadratic(vals):
  sgn_matrix = np.sign(np.expand_dims(vals, -1) - np.expand_dims(vals, -2))
  return np.prod(np.tril(np.ones_like(sgn_matrix)) + np.triu(sgn_matrix, 1))

def sub_quadratic(vals):
  #algorithm quicker than quadratic time?

sgn = quadratic(vals)
print(sgn)   #prints +1 

psgn = quadratic(pvals)
print(psgn)  #prints -1 (because one permutation)
```

I have had a look around SO ([here for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65923/how-does-one-compute-the-sign-of-a-permutation)) and people keep talking about cyclic permutations which apparently can compute in linear time but it's something I'm unaware of completely and can't find much of myself.

**TL;DR** Does anyone know of a method for computing the sign of a permutation in sub-quadratic time ?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's faster to use ```np.sign(vals[:, np.newaxis] - vals)``` instead of ```np.sign(np.expand_dims(vals, -1) - np.expand_dims(vals, -2))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decompose it into transpositions and check whether you needed an even or odd number of transpositions:

```
def permutation_sign(perm):
    parity = 1
    perm = perm.copy()
    for i in range(len(perm)):
        while perm[i] != i+1:
            parity *= -1
            j = perm[i] - 1
            # Note: if you try to inline the j computation into the next line,
            # you'll get evaluation order bugs.
            perm[i], perm[j] = perm[j], perm[i]
    return parity
```

Comment: But you haven't said anything about the runtime. I think this algorithm is quadratic? If so, then this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @A.Kriegman: It's linear. Every time the inner loop executes an iteration, the number of "out-of-place" elements decreases by at least 1, so the total number of iterations of the inner loop across all iterations of the outer loop is bounded by `len(perm)`.